# retrieving id of notification that is inserted using PublishAsync method is not implemented

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with Code-First Entity Framework and MVC 5.

and in order to send a notification I am using the following code

```
public async Task SendNotification(Guid auditId, int auditNo, int? tenantId, long userId)
        {
            var notificationData = new LocalizableMessageNotificationData(
                new LocalizableString(
                    "NotificationName",
                    EODAConsts.LocalizationSourceName
                )
            );
            notificationData["auditNo"] = auditNo;
            notificationData["auditId"] = auditId;
            await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(NotificationName, notificationData, severity: NotificationSeverity.Error, userIds: new[] { new UserIdentifier(tenantId, userId) });
        }
```

we know that sending the notification means adding  it to `AbpTenantNotifications` and `AbpUserNotifications` ,but after sending it what is the way to retrieve inserted notification id in `AbpTenantNotifications`  ,because  `PublishAsync` method doesn't return any value

i mean what is the unique key in table `AbpTenantNotifications` which insures selecting specific one notification that is inserted after calling PublishAsync method

Answer (score 1):

`NotificationInfo` only persist in the table for a short time only.

When you calls `PublishAsync`, `NotifcationInfo` is created immediately (see [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/58482d9a5dcf1e08375e94a2c152f920b15983f7/src/Abp/Notifications/NotificationPublisher.cs#L113)).

Subsequently, it is consumed by `NotificationDistributor.DistributeAsync` and deleted right after converting `NotificationInfo` into `TenantNotification` & `UserNotification` (see [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/58482d9a5dcf1e08375e94a2c152f920b15983f7/src/Abp/Notifications/DefaultNotificationDistributer.cs#L55))

If you want to capture the `TenantNotification` when it is created, you can try with entity event handler (see [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EventBus-Domain-Events))

Comment: Actually, *`NotificationInfo`* is created immediately and deleted right after converting *`NotificationInfo`* to *`TenantNotification` and* `UserNotification` (see [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/41c26d48faa0eedd9463f83f764afec020216a03/src/Abp/Notifications/DefaultNotificationDistributer.cs#L174-L189)).

Comment: how to get tenant notification id that is inserted ? what query should i apply tin order to get same inserted notification id

Comment: As mentioned, there is no simple way to get the Id for Tenant Notificaion when you call PublishAsync. If you want to handle the Id upon the creation of Tenant origination, use EventHandler